# What causes a light bulb to fluoresce?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, fluorescence

When an incandescent light bulb or fluorescent light bulb is pumped up with energy from the power grid, presumably light is subsequently emitted via transitions from the molecular excited state to it's ground state. What is causing this emission? Is it caused by quantum fluctuating vacuum electric fields that couple the molecular eigenstates, or is the emission driven by classical electric fields due to collisions with other molecules, the electrical current from the power grid, etc...?

Comment: Incandescents do not use any type of fluorescence; they use black-body (thermal) radiation instead

Comment: When a black body emits radiation, is this not just a thermally excited molecule fluorescing?

Comment: Fluorescence is what happens when an electron drops down from one orbital to a lower-energy one. Thermal radiation is caused by movement of atoms/molecules. The resulting charge acceleration or dipole oscillation produces electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: For a quantum black body, isn't the latter charge acceleration you mention simply a transition between molecular eigenstates that emits light?

Answer (score -1):

Fluorescence is a type of luminescence. Luminescence is defined as spontaneous emission of light not resulting from heat.

On the other hand, incandescence, is the emission of light from a hot body as a result of temperature.

Therefore, fluorescence by definition is spontaneous emission.

Photoluminescence is a type of luminescence, where light is emitted after the absorption of photons.

Fluorescence is a type of photoluminescence where it is a result of singlet-singlet electronic relaxation.

> > Fluorescence occurs when an orbital electron of a molecule, atom, or nanostructure, relaxes to its ground state by emitting a photon from an excited singlet state

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminescence

I do understand that you are confused by stimulated emission, but in reality in the case of stimulated emission, the electron drops to a lower energy level due to the interaction with a second (in some cases the first photon excited the electron already, but the excitation might have happened by other means too) incident photon.

> > Stimulated emission is the process by which an incoming photon of a specific frequency can interact with an excited atomic electron (or other excited molecular state), causing it to drop to a lower energy level.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_emission

In the case of fluorescence, the excited electron (that was excited by the absorption of a photon) undergoes spontaneous emission.

Now your edited question is basically asking about the cause/trigger of spontaneous emission by an atom inside a molecule of a fluorescent bulb.

> > The rate of emission depends on two factors: an 'atomic part', which describes the internal structure of the light source and a 'field part', which describes the density of electromagnetic modes of the environment.

Now you are basically asking about the field part, and the Dicke effect.

You are correct, that the atom inside the fluorescent bulb will have a different emission rate from an atom in free space. The difference is the field part.

> > The spontaneous emission from N strongly interacting emitters can be very different from
> >     their independent behavior, and a coherence that increases the probability of spontaneous
> >     emission (and radiated power) by N2
> >      is called the Dicke effect.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.07455

The Dicke effect in spectroscopy, refers to the Doppler broadening of the spectral line due to collisions of the emitting particle with other atoms.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicke_effect

So to answer your question, you are correct, the emitting atom's interaction with the other atoms will change the emission rate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98591/discussion-on-answer-by-arpad-szendrei-what-causes-a-light-bulb-to-fluoresce).

Comment: why the downvote?